# CSS is only displayed when is put inside <style> tag

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a view but my CSS is not displaying except if I put it inside a `<style>` I already tried using `!important` but didn't work too, also tried `.container-fluid > .row > .d-flex > .out_profile`

The class `out_profile` is not working the CSS inside that class is not displayed. To see the snippet you have to put it on small devices using the responsive

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
    .container-fluid{
        display: none;
    }
    .container-fluid > .row > .d-flex > .out_profile {
        color: #662483 !important;
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" TYPE="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center navbar navbar-light bg-light col-12">
                <div class="out_profile">
                    X
                </div>
                <span class="navbar-brand mb-0"><h3 style="color: #662483 !important;">Profile</h3></span>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, mostly because Stack Snippets adds the CSS in a `<style>` tag, so, for instance, `.container-fluid` is set as `display: none` so your example shows nothing.

Comment: Could you explain a little better what the problem is? The `display: none` seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Yeah, everything is working just as expected. As per your media query in CSS, at screen-width>=576px, the container is not visible. Could you please explain what is your problem ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the class `out_profile` is not working the CSS inside that class is not displayed, the `container-fluid` has a `display: none` because only works on small devices @HereticMonkey

Comment: See my updated question @Shraddha

Comment: The way you css is setup it is saying: HIDE container-fluid and all of its children. Then set the font color of one of its children to a different color. If your CSS was working properly, the font color shouldn't be visible as that element isn't visible.

Comment: As per your CSS, you are hiding the container and at the same time you are trying to change the color of the text. Think @JakeParis has nicely explained you the situation and have clarified your doubt.Thankyou..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took out the `display: none` and it seems to do exactly what you'd expect -- the text is purple (see example below).

Having said that, I don't think

```css
.container-fluid > .row > .d-flex > .out_profile
```

is a very elegant css selector. Perhaps you are new to css, but except in very limited circumstances would you need the `>` selector. In most cases, you would simple write:

```css
 .container-fluid .row .d-flex .out_profile
```

and you can probably even leave a few of the middle elements out, but depends on your situation.

And, as HereticMonkey has pointed out, a `!important` in css code *rarely* necessary, so it most likely isn't here either. I left it in below just to show that the only thing I changed was to remove the display: none.

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) { 

    .container-fluid > .row > .d-flex > .out_profile {
        color: #662483 !important;
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" TYPE="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center navbar navbar-light bg-light col-12">
                <div class="out_profile">
                    X
                </div>
                <span class="navbar-brand mb-0"><h3 style="color: #662483 !important;">Profile</h3></span>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In almost all cases, `.out_profile { color: #662483; }` would be sufficient. The opportunities to actually use `!important` for a good reason are so few and far between I usually tell people on my projects not to use it, and if they feel they have to, come to me. I've led lots of projects with lots of developers and have had two times where it was necessary, and only because a component library used inline styles.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You don't need to tell _me_ that!! :D

Comment: Oh, I know, I just saw your answer still had it in there and thought I'd leave some color for the next person who came across the answer. Thanks for the edit :).